# Salesforce Org Shape not working with sfdx: "Can't create org shape."

Tags: salesforcedx, org-shape

I enabled org shape in my production org.

I entered the Org ID of my Staging org as the developer hub. My staging org is a partial copy sandbox of production. My staging org does **not** have "org shape" available in setup.

Then on the command line I ran:

```
sfdx forcorg:shape:create -u Staging
```

And got the error:

> ERROR running force:org:shape:create:  Can't create org shape. Contact the org admin to enable Org Shape for Scratch Orgs in `Setup > Org Shape` in a supported org. Then try again.

My sfdx version:

```
sfdx --version
sfdx-cli/7.110.0 darwin-x64 node-v14.9.0
```

Comment: I hope it is not supported in sandboxes as per this [article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_shape_enable_org_shape.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Guess ORG shape is not available in Sandboxes as per [article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_shape_enable_org_shape.htm).

> Available in: Developer, Group, Professional, Unlimited, and Enterprise editions

> Not available in: Scratch orgs and sandboxes

Comment: Thank you. What a backwards ecosystem.